# Diff command in bash

Tags: bash, diff

Every time i run the following bash command, i get an error:

Here's the code:

```
sort -b ./tests/out/$scenario > $studentFile
sort -b ./tests/out/$scenario > $profFile
$(diff $studentFile $profFile)
  if [ $? -eq 0 ]
      then 
          echo "Files are equal!"
      else
          echo "Files are different!"
      fi
```

Here's the error:

```
./test.sh: 2c2: not found
```

I basically want to sort two files, and then check if they are equal or not. What i don't understand is what this error means and how i can get rid of it. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Any spaces, stars, or other special characters in the filenames or paths?

Comment: no, just regular text @user000001

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Short answer: use

```
diff $studentFile $profFile
```

instead of:

```
$(diff $studentFile $profFile)
```

Long answer:

```
diff $studentFile $profFile
```

will provide an output of several lines, first one, in your example, is "2c2". If you enclose the diff command in $(), the result of this expression is an string with the concatenation of all the lines, "2c2 ...". In your script, this result is executed by bash as new command, with the result of "command not found: 2c2".

Compare, by example:

```
$(diff $studentFile $profFile)
```

and:

```
echo $(diff $studentFile $profFile)
```

*** Addendum ***

```
if diff $studentFile $profFile > /dev/null 2>&1
then
  echo "equal files"
else
  echo "different files"
fi
```

is a possible way of reach the expected result.

Comment: Sorry i forgot the last part of the code i've edited it!

Comment: Same problem there: remove all `$( ... )` around the `diff` commands.

Comment: Thanks, turned out it was an easy fix!

Answer (score 2):

Your command

```
$(diff $studentFile $profFile)
```

executes the *result* of running the `diff` command on the two files. The `2c2` that your shell complains about is probably the first word in the output from `diff`.

I'm assuming that you simply want to see the output from `diff`:

```
diff $studentFile $profFile
```

If you want to compare the file for equality in a script, consider using `cmp`:

```
if cmp -s $studentFile $profFile; then
    # Handle file that are equal
else
    # Handle files that are different
fi
```

The `diff` utility is for inspecting differences between files, while `cmp` is much better suited for just simply testing if files are different (in a script, for example).

For more specialized cases there is the `comm` utility that compares lines in sorted files.

Comment: Sorry i forgot the last part of the code i've edited it now !

Comment: Uh, why? That's a strange requirement.

Comment: `cmp` is much more efficient than `diff`. I would say use `diff` when you want to see the difference in a nicely formatted way, but use `cmp` if you just want to compare for equality.